# XML parsing error for Content Security Policy

Tags: xml, parsing, syntax

I'm having trouble getting the XML syntax correct for my blog's content security policy. It works when it's simple, but as soon as I add more policies, I get a parsing error.

**Current policy (works):**

`<meta http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy' content='upgrade-insecure-requests'/>`

**New policy (parse error):**

`<meta http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy' content='upgrade-insecure-requests';'report-uri' 'https://redacted.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce'/>`

**Error:** Element type "meta" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

I've read up on XML syntax and looked at examples confirming that the contents should be delimited with a semicolon, and each policy is space delimited. I've tried with and without quotes on the strings, and adjusting the spacing, but I just can't figure out this parsing error. I am more familiar with Python, so I'm sure this is a simple issue to someone who is more experienced with XML. Thank you for helping out an XML newbie! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing two "layers" in the way you're understanding the markup. As far as XML and HTML is concerned, there are only attributes and their values:

```
<meta http-equiv='some value' content='some value' />
```

Note that the values are each delimited by matching quotes, which could be either `'` or `"`. Inside those quotes can be anything at all, *except for something that would be mistaken for an ending quote mark*.

If you try to put `'` inside the value, the HTML/XML parser sees that as the end of the value, and then doesn't know what to do with what comes next; it basically sees this:

```
<meta http-equiv='some value' content='some value' some-unexpected-text />
```

The semicolon-separated list is all *inside* the value of an attribute, understood by some other tool (the CSP definition):

```
upgrade-insecure-requests; report-uri https://redacted.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce
```

So your markup should look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy' content='upgrade-insecure-requests; report-uri https://redacted.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce' />
```

Comment: Oh wow I knew it was something simple that I was just overlooking. I can confirm it's parsing fine now, thanks a bunch!